# Best Way To Take multiple TCP Connections, Read the Incoming Data, and send that Data back into the Main Thread in Golang?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, go

I want to take data from my goroutines and add them back to the main thread/goroutine. Problem is that I need the goroutines to stay open because data can come through the connection at any time in the program.

I can think of two ways to do it possibly...

1. Use channels somehow. I am not quite sure how to do it this way, but I have a feeling there might be a way to do it.
2. In each goroutine, add to a queue and read from it in the main thread. Make sure to lock the queue whenever someone adds/reads from it. Also, you would need to find how to make the main thread continue running when the goroutines also keep running in the background.

Which option do you guys think is better? Also, how would you guys go about solving the problem? If there is another better way also feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, both suggestions can be used with channels, because channels are a thread-safe queues.

So here is an example of 3 connections to different HTTP services run in their own goroutines and send back data to the main goroutine via a unique channel:

```go
package main

import(
    "net"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)


func reader(muxChan chan []byte, conn net.Conn, readerID int) {
    // We close the connection at any exit points
    defer conn.Close()

    _, err := conn.Write([]byte("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // we read conn data in a 256 bytes slice
    b := make([]byte, 256)
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(b)
        if err == io.EOF {
            // We reached EOF, let’s close that goroutine
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("reading error:", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%d: data(%d bytes): %s\n", readerID,n, string(b[:n]))//buf.String())

        // We copy the current byte slice to a new byte slice that is passed through the mux channel
        out := make([]byte, n)
        copy(out, b)
        // We send the new byte slice back to the main goroutine that ranges over the muxChan data
        muxChan <- out
    }
}

func main() {
    // We create the mux channel that will receive data from all the connections
    muxChan := make(chan []byte)

    connGH, err := net.Dial("tcp", "github.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    connG, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    connSO, err := net.Dial("tcp", "stackoverflow.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Let’s send those connections into their own goroutines
    go reader(muxChan, connGH, 1)
    go reader(muxChan, connG, 2)
    go reader(muxChan, connSO, 3)

    // We iterate over the data that will come from that channel
    for data := range muxChan {
        fmt.Println("muxed:", string(data), "\n")
    }
}
```